# How can I assign or fix special op during convert processing in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I've encountered a problem in convert tensorflow session to tensorflow lite model.
The problem is `TFLiteConverter` enforces use `FlexFloorDiv` to replace the original function(`tf.floordiv`), and `FlexFloorDiv` is not supported in tflite.
But I already check the tflite's API list, and I find tflite supports `floor_div` (https://tensorflow.google.cn/mlir/tfl_ops#tflfloor_div_mlirtflfloordivop).
I want get a conversion that is originally supported by tflite, in other words, I wish only to use `'tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS'`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.__version__ > '2':
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf  
    tf.disable_v2_behavior()


tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
inputs = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[20, 4])

maxloc = tf.argmax(input=inputs, axis=0)
inputs_shape = tf.shape(input=inputs)

# Here is the error code
# the converter will use FlexFloorDiv not floor_div
out = tf.floordiv(maxloc, tf.cast(inputs_shape[1], tf.int64))

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.compat.v1.local_variables_initializer())
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, [inputs], [out])
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
# converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS] # can not convert.
converter.allow_custom_ops = False
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

The output is:

```py
2022-01-21 18:01:40.286574: W tensorflow/compiler/mlir/lite/flatbuffer_export.cc:1891] TFLite interpreter needs to link Flex delegate in order to run the model since it contains the following Select TFop(s):
Flex ops: FlexFloorDiv
Details:
        tf.FloorDiv(tensor<4xi64>, tensor<i64>) -> (tensor<4xi64>) : {device = ""}
See instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select
2022-01-21 18:01:40.286641: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/lite/flatbuffer_export.cc:1962] Estimated count of arithmetic ops: 0  ops, equivalently 0  MACs
```

Comment: What is the version of Tensorflow that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe tensorflow-lite not friendly for div operator of int32\int64 type, it will convert to tf.RealDiv or tf.FlexDiv, and they are not supported by original tflite.
For get my target, here i use a float32 div instead of int64 div, the code like that:

```py
maxloc = tf.argmax(input=inputs, axis=0)
inputs_shape = tf.shape(input=inputs)
out = tf.cast(out, tf.float32) / tf.cast(inputs_shape [1], tf.float32)
# use cutoff feature when from float to int, we can get floor operator.  
out = tf.cast(out , tf.int64)
```